# MySQL-8.0.12 slave replication failed

Tags: mysql, replication

I use MySQL-8.0.12 to setup a master-slave replication cluster. But slave always gets following errors, does anyone know how to fix this ?

> 2018-11-01T04:17:58.327576Z 19 [ERROR] [MY-010834] [Server] next log
>   error: -1  offset: 50  log: ./mysql-relay-bin.000002 included: 1,
>
> 2018-11-01T04:17:58.327675Z 19 [ERROR] [MY-010596] [Repl] Error
>   reading relay log event for channel '': Error purging processed logs,
>
> 2018-11-01T04:17:58.327932Z 19 [ERROR] [MY-013121] [Repl] Slave SQL
>   for channel '': Relay log read failure: Could not parse relay log
>   event entry. The possible reasons are: the master's binary log is
>   corrupted (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the binary
>   log), the slave's relay log is corrupted (you can check this by
>   running 'mysqlbinlog' on the relay log), a network problem, or a bug
>   in the master's or slave's MySQL code. If you want to check the
>   master's binary log or slave's relay log, you will be able to know
>   their names by issuing 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' on this slave. Error_code:
>   MY-013121,
>
> 2018-11-01T04:17:58.327982Z 19 [ERROR] [MY-010586] [Repl] Error
>   running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart
>   the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log
>   'mysql-bin.000003' position 805

Comment: Once I've encountered the same problem but later found that I use different version of mysql in master and slave. This is an old post, but just in case somebody is searching for possible cause, version difference could be it.

Answer (score 0):

check disk space in slave
faced the same issue once.
during the replication, if slave server disk is full and no space left mysql replication thread wait for the disk to be freed wait time is 60 sec if the server restarted during that time then relay log cannot be recovered and slave cannot read the relay log.